# Apply function to list of dataframes and columns matching pattern

Tags: r, regex, list, function, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and I would like to apply a function to specific columns that follow a pattern across all the dataframes in the list.

Here is an example list of dataframes:

```
k_2 <- data.frame(Site = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",2)), V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), V2 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
k_3 <- data.frame(Site = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",2)), V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), V2 = c(1,2,3,4,5), V3 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
k_4 <- data.frame(Site = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",2)), V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), V2 = c(1,2,3,4,5), V3 = c(1,2,3,4,5), V4 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
my.list <- list(k_2, k_3, k_4)
my.list
```

I want to apply this

```
k2_res <- ddply(k_2, "Site", function(x) colSums(x[c("V1", "V2")])/nrow(x))
```

to all the dataframes in the list. However, for K_3 the calculation will need to be `colSums(x[c("V1","V2","V3")])` and k_4 will go up to `V4` and so on.

**Ideas**

I thought that maybe I could use some sort of `grep` or `regrex` to automatically select all the columns beginning with V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like below?

```
lapply(
  my.list,
  function(df) ddply(df, "Site", function(x) colSums(x[grepl("V\\d+", names(x))]) / nrow(x))
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! Would you mind explaining the `grepl()` to me? Also why use `grepl` versus `grep`?

Comment: @QPaps `grepl` gives logic value regarding the matched pattern in a string, `grep` gives the indices. You can type `?grepl` in the console to see its usage.

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense! Thank you very much :D have a wonderful day!